# Exec Error at line 170: division by zero (0) GAMS code

Tags: error-handling, gams-math

I have started the GAMS adventure after the R studio adventure. I am encountering an error while doing my modelling work, but I could not find it. I have a variable divided by 0, but I could not solve the problem.

Problem:  **** Exec Error at line 170: division by zero (0)

I'm open to any code improvements.

On the other hand; where I use display and exit codes gives me the opportunity to see my mistakes.

Best Regards,
OK

````
   1   
   2  *=================================*
   3  *    Environmental CGE model      *
   4  *=================================*
   5   
   6   
   7  Sets
   8               i Sectors /Industrie, Services, Combustiles, Poll_Elec, NonPo
      ll_Elec/
   9               f Factors /L, K/;
  10   
  11   
  12  Alias(i,ii);
  13  Parameter SAM(*,*);
LIBINCLUDE C:\GAMS\41\inclib\xlimport.gms
  46  Display SAM;
  47   
  48   
  49  Parameters
  50  alpha_VA(i)               Parameter in the first nest of the CES productio
      n functions
  51  alpha_Fd_Industrie(f)     Parameter in the second nest of the CES producti
      on functions
  52  alpha_Fd_Services(f)      Parameter in the second nest of the CES producti
      on functions
  53  alpha_Fd_Poll_Elec(f)     Parameter in the second nest of the CES producti
      on functions
  54  alpha_Fd_NonPoll_Elec(f)  Parameter in the second nest of the CES producti
      on functions
  55   
  56  alpha_IntTot(i)           Parameter in the first nest of the CES productio
      n functions
  57  alpha_Int_Industrie(i)    Parameter in the second nest of the CES producti
      on functions
  58  alpha_Int_Services(i)     Parameter in the second nest of the CES producti
      on functions
  59  alpha_Int_Poll_Elec(i)    Parameter in the second nest of the CES producti
      on functions
  60  alpha_Int_NonPoll_Elec(i) Parameter in the second nest of the CES producti
      on functions
  61   
  62  sigma_VA(i)               Elasticity of substitution in the second nest of
       the CES production functions
  63  sigma_Int(i)              Elasticity of substitution in the second nest of
       the CES production functions
  64   
  65   
  66  alpha_Energy_NonEn        Parameter in the first nest of the CES utility f
      unction
  67  alpha_C_NonEn(i)          Parameter in the second nest of the CES utility 
      function
  68  alpha_C_Energy(i)         Parameter in the second nest of the CES utility 
      function
  69  sigma_C                   Elasticity of substitution in the second nest of
       the CES utility function
  70   
  71  Fd0_Industrie(f)          Demand of factor f by industry
  72  Fd0_Services(f)           Demand of factor f by services
  73  Fd0_Poll_Elec(f)          Demand of factor f by elec_p
  74  Fd0_NonPoll_Elec(f)       Demand of factor f by elec_np
  75   
  76  P0(i)                     Price of commodity i
  77  Pva0(i)                   Aggregate price of production factors (L and K)
  78  Pint0(i)                  Aggregate price of intermediate inputs
  79  Pc0(i)                    Consumer price index
  80  P_Other0(i)               Aggregate price of materials (Industry and Servi
      ces)
  81  P_Energy0(i)              Aggregate price of energy (Poll_E and NonPoll_E)
  82  W0(f)                     Price of factor f
  83  Xs0(i)                    Production of sector i
  84  VA0(i)                    Value added of sector i
  85   
  86  Other_aggr0(i)            Aggregate level of materials (Industry and Servi
      ces)
  87  Energy_aggr0(i)           Aggregate level of energy (Poll_E and NonPoll_E)
  88  Pc_NonEn0                 Consumer price index of non-energy commodities
  89  Pc_Energy0                Consumer price index of     energy commodities (
      included fuels)
  90   
  91  Fd0(i,f)                  Demand of factor f by sector i
  92  Fs0(i,f)                  Supply of factor f by households
  93   
  94  IntTot0(i)                Total intermediate inputs demanded by sector i
  95  Int0_Industrie(i)         Intermediate inputs demanded by sector industry 
      to sector i
  96  Int0_Services(i)          Intermediate inputs demanded by sector services 
      to sector i
  97  Int0_Poll_Elec(i)         Intermediate inputs demanded by sector elec_p  t
      o sector i
  98  Int0_NonPoll_Elec(i)      Intermediate inputs demanded by sector elec_np  
      to sector i
  99  Int0_Combustiles(i)       Intermediate inputs demanded by sector fuel  to 
      sector i
 100   
 101  Y0(i)                     Income of households
 102  Xd0(i)                    Demand of commodity i by households
 103  C0                        Aggregate consumption
 104  C_NonEn0                  Aggregate consumption of non-energy commodities
 105  C_Energy0                 Aggregate consumption of energy commodities
 106  CO2_H                     CO2 emission coefficients for consumption
 107   
 108  P_Fuel0(i)                Aggregate price of fuels (Fuel)
 109  Emissions0                Total emissions of C02
 110  tax_CO2(i)                Carbon tax
 111  T_E                       Taux d'epargne
 112  S_RDM(i)                  Taux d'epargne du RDM
 113   
 114  INV_Industrie0(i)         Industrial Investment
 115  Pinv0                     Aggregate price of investment goods
 116   
 117   
 118   
 119  Permits                   Scalar Permits "Carbon permits"
 120   
 121  ;
 122   
 123   
 124   
 125   
 126  * Calibration of the parameters and initialization of the endogenous varia
      bles
 127   
 128  P0(i)                   = 1;
 129  Pva0(i)                 = 1;
 130  Pc0(i)                  = 1;
 131  Pc_NonEn0               = 1;
 132  Pc_Energy0              = 1;
 133  P_Other0(i)             = 1;
 134  P_Energy0(i)            = 1;
 135  Pint0(i)                = 1;
 136  W0(f)                   = 1;
 137  Pinv0                   = 1;
 138  T_E                     = 0.15;
 139  Xd0(i)                  = SAM(i,"H");
 140  C0                      = Sum(i, Xd0(i));
 141  C_NonEn0                = Sum(i $ (ord(i) LE 2), Xd0(i));
 142  C_Energy0               = Sum(i $ (ord(i) GE 3), Xd0(i));
 143  Xs0(i)                  = SAM(i,"Total");
 144  Fd0_Industrie(f)        = SAM(f,"Industrie");
 145  Fd0_Services(f)         = SAM(f,"Services");
 146  Fd0_Poll_Elec(f)        = SAM(f,"Poll_Elec");
 147  Fd0_NonPoll_Elec(f)     = SAM(f,"NonPoll_Elec");
 148  Fs0(i,f)                = SAM(i,f);
 149  Int0_Industrie(i)       = SAM(i,"Industrie");
 150  Int0_Services(i)        = SAM(i,"Services");
 151  Int0_Poll_Elec(i)       = SAM(i,"Poll_Elec");
 152  Int0_NonPoll_Elec(i)    = SAM(i,"NonPoll_Elec");
 153  IntTot0("Industrie")    = Sum(i, Int0_Industrie(i));
 154  IntTot0("Services")     = Sum(i, Int0_Services(i));
 155  IntTot0("Poll_Elec")    = Sum(i, Int0_Poll_Elec(i));
 156  IntTot0("NonPoll_Elec") = Sum(i, Int0_NonPoll_Elec(i));
 157  VA0("Industrie")        = Sum(f, Fd0_Industrie(f));
 158  VA0("Services")         = Sum(f, Fd0_Services(f));
 159  VA0("Poll_Elec")        = Sum(f, Fd0_Poll_Elec(f));
 160  VA0("NonPoll_Elec")     = Sum(f, Fd0_NonPoll_Elec(f));
 161  INV_Industrie0(i)       = SAM(i,"Epargne");
 162  S_RDM(i)                = SAM(i,"Epargne") / SAM("Epargne","RDM");
 163  sigma_Int("Industrie")  = 0.5;
 164  sigma_Int("Services")   = 0.5;
 165  sigma_Int("Poll_Elec")     = 2 ;
 166  sigma_Int("NonPoll_Elec")    = 2 ;
 167  alpha_Int_Industrie(i)  = (Int0_Industrie(i) /IntTot0("Industrie")) ** (1/
      sigma_Int("Industrie"));
 168  alpha_Int_Services(i)   = (Int0_Services(i) /IntTot0("Services")) ** (1/si
      gma_Int("Services"));
 169  alpha_Int_Poll_Elec(i)     = (Int0_Poll_Elec(i) /IntTot0("Poll_Elec")) ** 
      (1/sigma_Int("Poll_Elec"));
 170  alpha_Int_NonPoll_Elec(i)    = (Int0_NonPoll_Elec(i) /IntTot0("NonPoll_Ele
      c")) ** (1/sigma_Int("NonPoll_Elec"));
 171  sigma_C                 = 0.5;
 172  alpha_C_NonEn(i)        = (Xd0(i)/C_NonEn0) **(1/sigma_C);
 173  alpha_C_Energy(i)       = (Xd0(i)/C_Energy0)**(1/sigma_C);
 174  Fs0(i,f)                = SAM("H",f);
 175  Y0(i)                   = SAM("H","Total");
 176  alpha_VA(i)             = VA0(i)/Xs0(i);
 177  sigma_VA(i)             = 0.5;
 178  alpha_Fd_Industrie(f)   = (Fd0_Industrie(f)/VA0("Industrie"))**(1/sigma_VA
      ("Industrie"));
 179  alpha_Fd_Services(f)    = (Fd0_Services(f)/VA0("Services"))**(1/sigma_VA("
      Services"));
 180  alpha_Fd_Poll_Elec(f)   = (Fd0_Poll_Elec(f)/VA0("Poll_Elec"))**(1/sigma_VA
      ("Poll_Elec"));
 181  alpha_Fd_NonPoll_Elec(f)= (Fd0_NonPoll_Elec(f)/VA0("NonPoll_Elec"))**(1/si
      gma_VA("NonPoll_Elec"));
 182   
 183  Parameter CO2_H;
 184  CO2_H                   = 0.8;
 185   
 186  Parameter CO2;
 187  CO2("Industry")         = 1;
 188  CO2("Services")         = 0.5;
 189  CO2("Poll_Elec")        = 1.2;
 190   
 191  Int0_Combustiles(i)     = 0;
 192  *Emissions0              = Sum(i, CO2(i)*Int0("Combustiles",i)) + CO2_H*Xd
      0("Combustiles");
 193  Emissions0              = Sum(i, CO2(i)*Int0_Combustiles(i)) + CO2_H*Xd0("
      Combustiles");
 194   
 195  tax_CO2(i)              = 0;
 196   
 197  Permits                 = 1000;
 198   
 199  Display alpha_Fd_Industrie, alpha_Fd_Services,alpha_Fd_Poll_Elec, alpha_Fd
      _NonPoll_Elec,W0,P0,Y0,Xd0,Xs0,Fd0_Industrie,Fd0_Services,Fd0_Poll_Elec,Fd
      0_NonPoll_Elec,Fs0,CO2, CO2_H;
 200   
 201   
 202   
 203  Variables
 204  P(i)                     Price of commodity i
 205  Pva(i)                   Aggregate price of production factors (L and K)
 206  Pint(i)                  Aggregate price of the second aggregate
 207  Pc(i)                    Consumer price index of individual
 208  Pinv                     Aggregate price of investment goods
 209  P_Other(i)               Aggregate price of materials (Industry and Servic
      es)
 210  P_Energy(i)              Aggregate price of energy (Poll_E and NonPoll_E)
 211  W(f)                     Price of factor f
 212  Pc_NonEn                 Consumer price index of non-energy commodities
 213  Pc_Energy                Consumer price index of energy commodities (inclu
      ded fuels)
 214  Xs(i)                    Production of sector i
 215  VA(i)                    Value added of sector i
 216  Other_aggr(i)            Aggregate level of materials (Industry and Servic
      es)
 217  Energy_aggr(i)           Aggregate level of energy (Poll_E and NonPoll_E)
 218  Fd_Industrie(f)          Demand of factor f by Industry
 219  Fd_Services(f)           Demand of factor f by services
 220  Fd_Poll_Elec(f)          Demand of factor f by Poll_Elec
 221  Fd_NonPoll_Elec(f)       Demand of factor f by NonPoll_Elec
 222  IntTot(i)                Second aggregate of the production by sector i
 223  Int_Industrie(i)         Intermediate inputs demanded by Industry to secto
      r i
 224  Int_Services(i)          Intermediate inputs demanded by Services to secto
      r i
 225  Int_Poll_Elec(i)         Intermediate inputs demanded by Poll_Elec to sect
      or i
 226  Int_NonPoll_Elec(i)      Intermediate inputs demanded by NonPoll_Elec to s
      ector i
 227  Y(i)                     Income of households
 228  Xd(i)                    Demand of commodity i by households
 229  C                        Aggregate consumption
 230  C_NonEn                  Aggregate consumption of non-energy commodities
 231  C_Energy                 Aggregate consumption of     energy commodities
 232  Fs(i,f)                  Supply of factor f by households
 233  Emissions                Total emissions of CO2
 234  IMP                      Total des importations
 235  INV_Industrie            Industry Invesment
 236  P_Fuel                   Price of Combustiles
 237  Pp(i)                    Price of emission permits
 238  Walras
 239  Obj
 240  ;
 241   
 242  *===================================*
 243  *      Variable initialization      *
 244  *===================================*
 245   
 246  P.L(i)               = P0(i);
 247  Pva.L(i)             = Pva0(i);
 248  Pint.L(i)            = Pint0(i);
 249  Pinv.L               = Pinv0;
 250  W.L(f)               = W0(f);
 251  P_Other.L(i)         = P_Other0(i);
 252  P_Energy.L(i)        = P_Energy0(i);
 253  Xs.L(i)              = Xs0(i);
 254  VA.L(i)              = VA0(i);
 255  IntTot.L(i)          = IntTot0(i);
 256  Fd_Industrie.L(f)    = Fd0_Industrie(f);
 257  Fd_Services.L(f)     = Fd0_Services(f);
 258  Fd_Poll_Elec.L(f)    = Fd0_Poll_Elec(f);
 259  Fd_NonPoll_Elec.L(f) = Fd0_NonPoll_Elec(f);
 260  Int_Industrie.L(i)   = Int0_Industrie(i);
 261  Int_Services.L(i)    = Int0_Services(i);
 262  Int_Poll_Elec.L(i)   = Int0_Poll_Elec(i);
 263  Int_NonPoll_Elec.L(i)= Int0_NonPoll_Elec(i);
 264  Y.L(i)               = Y0(i);
 265  Xd.L(i)              = Xd0(i);
 266  C.L                  = C0;
 267  C_NonEn.L            = C_NonEn0;
 268  C_Energy.L           = C_Energy0;
 269   
 270  *===================================*
 271  *         Exogenous variables       *
 272  *===================================*
 273  *Fs.Fx(f)                                                      = Fs0(f);
 274   
 275  *Other_aggr.Fx(i)  $ (alpha_Other_aggr(i)  EQ 0)               = 0;
 276  *Fuels_aggr.Fx(i)  $ (alpha_Fuels_aggr(i)  EQ 0)               = 0;
 277  *Energy_aggr.Fx(i) $ (alpha_Energy_aggr(i) EQ 0)               = 0;
 278   
 279  *Int.Fx(ii,i) $ (ord(ii) LE 2 and alpha_Int_Other(ii,i)  EQ 0) = 0;
 280  *Int.Fx(ii,i) $ (ord(ii) EQ 3 and alpha_Int_Fuels(ii,i)  EQ 0) = 0;
 281  *Int.Fx(ii,i) $ (ord(ii) GE 4 and alpha_Int_Energy(ii,i) EQ 0) = 0;
 282   
 283  *P_Other.Fx(i)  $ (alpha_Other_aggr(i)  EQ 0)                  = 0;
 284  *P_Fuels.Fx(i)  $ (alpha_Fuels_aggr(i)  EQ 0)                  = 0;
 285  *P_Energy.Fx(i) $ (alpha_Energy_aggr(i) EQ 0)                  = 0;
 286   
 287  *Pp.Fx("Industry")                                             = 0;
 288  *Pp.Fx("Services")                                             = 0;
 289  *Pp.Fx("Poll_Elec")                                            = 0;
 290  *Pp.Fx("NonPoll_E")                                            = 0;
 291   
 292  *G.Fx("Industry")                                              = 0;
 293  *G.Fx("Services")                                              = 0;
 294  *G.Fx("Fuel")                                                  = 0;
 295  *G.Fx("Poll_Elec")                                             = 0;
 296   
 297  *===================================*
 298  *             Numeraire             *
 299  *===================================*
 300  W.Fx("L")                                                     = 1;
 301   
 302  Equations
 303  Eq1(i)
 304  Eq2(i)
 305  Eq3(i)
 306  Eq4(f)
 307  Eq5
 308  Eq6(i)
 309  Eq7
 310  Eq8(f)
 311  Eq9
 312  Eq10(i)
 313  Eq11
 314  Eq12(f)
 315  Eq13
 316  Eq14(i)
 317  Eq15
 318  Eq16(f)
 319  Eq17
 320  Eq18(i)
 321  Eq19
 322  Eq20(i)
 323  Eq21
 324  Eq22(i)
 325  Eq23
 326  Eq24(i)
 327  Eq25(i)
 328  Eq26
 329  Eq27
 330  Eq28
 331  Eq29
 332  Eq30(i)
 333  ;
 334   
 335  *       Secteurs d'activité
 336   
 337  *la technologie de tous les secteurs est la même (à l'exception du secteur
       des combustibles).
 338  *le niveau de production est déterminé par une fonction CES à deux niveaux
      .
 339   
 340  Eq1(i)..           VA(i)                     =E= alpha_VA(i)*Xs(i);
 341  * VA(i)
 342   
 343  Eq2(i)..           IntTot(i)                 =E= alpha_IntTot(i)*Xs(i);
 344  * IntTot(i)
 345   
 346  Eq3(i)..           P(i)*Xs(i)                =E= Pva(i)*VA(i) + Pint(i)*In
      tTot(i);
 347  * Xs(i)
 348   
 349   
 350  *         Industry
 351   
 352  Eq4(f)..           Fd_Industrie(f)          =E= (alpha_Fd_Industrie(f) **s
      igma_VA("Industrie") * (Pva("Industrie")/W(f))**sigma_VA("Industrie") * VA
      ("Industrie"));
 353  * Fd_Industrie(f)
 354   
 355  Eq5..              Pva("Industrie")*VA("Industrie")         =E= Sum(f, W(f
      )*Fd_Industrie(f));
 356  * Pva("Industrie")
 357   
 358  Eq6(i)..           Int_Industrie(i)                 =E= alpha_Int_Industri
      e(i)**sigma_Int("Industrie") * (Pint("Industrie")/P(i))**sigma_Int("Indust
      rie") * IntTot("Industrie");
 359  * Int_Industrie(i)
 360   
 361  Eq7..               Pint("Industrie")*IntTot("Industrie")     =E= Sum(i, P
      (i)*Int_Industrie(i));
 362  * Pint("Industrie")
 363   
 364   
 365  *        Services
 366   
 367  Eq8(f)..           Fd_Services(f)          =E= (alpha_Fd_Services(f) **sig
      ma_VA("Services") * (Pva("Services")/W(f))**sigma_VA("Services") * VA("Ser
      vices"));
 368  * Fd_Services(f)
 369   
 370  Eq9..              Pva("Services")*VA("Services")         =E= Sum(f, W(f)*
      Fd_Services(f));
 371  * Pva("Services")
 372   
 373  Eq10(i)..           Int_Services(i)                 =E= alpha_Int_Industri
      e(i)**sigma_Int("Services") * (Pint("Services")/P(i))**sigma_Int("Services
      ") * IntTot("Services");
 374  * Int_Services(i)
 375   
 376  Eq11..               Pint("Services")*IntTot("Services")     =E= Sum(i, P(
      i)*Int_Services(i));
 377  * Pint("Services")
 378   
 379   
 380   
 381  *** Poll_Elec ***
 382   
 383  Eq12(f)..           Fd_Poll_Elec(f)          =E= (alpha_Fd_Poll_Elec(f) **
      sigma_VA("Poll_Elec") * (Pva("Poll_Elec")/W(f))**sigma_VA("Poll_Elec") * V
      A("Poll_Elec"));
 384  * Fd_Poll_Elecf)
 385   
 386  Eq13..              Pva("Poll_Elec")*VA("Poll_Elec")         =E= Sum(f, W(
      f)*Fd_Poll_Elec(f));
 387  * Pva("Poll_Elec")
 388   
 389  Eq14(i)..           Int_Poll_Elec(i)                 =E= alpha_Int_Poll_El
      ec(i)**sigma_Int("Poll_Elec") * (Pint("Poll_Elec")/P(i))**sigma_Int("Poll_
      Elec") * IntTot("Poll_Elec");
 390  * Int_Poll_Elec
 391   
 392  Eq15..               Pint("Poll_Elec")*IntTot("Poll_Elec")     =E= Sum(i, 
      P(i)*Int_Poll_Elec(i));
 393  * Pint("Poll_Elec")
 394   
 395   
 396  *** NonPoll_Elec ***
 397   
 398  Eq16(f)..           Fd_NonPoll_Elec(f)          =E= (alpha_Fd_NonPoll_Elec
      (f) **sigma_VA("NonPoll_Elec") * (Pva("NonPoll_Elec")/W(f))**sigma_VA("Non
      Poll_Elec") * VA("NonPoll_Elec"));
 399  * Fd_NonPoll_Elec(f)
 400   
 401  Eq17..              Pva("NonPoll_Elec")*VA("NonPoll_Elec")         =E= Sum
      (f, W(f)*Fd_NonPoll_Elec(f));
 402  * Pva("NonPoll_Elec")
 403   
 404  Eq18(i)..           Int_NonPoll_Elec(i)                 =E= alpha_Int_Poll
      _Elec(i)**sigma_Int("NonPoll_Elec") * (Pint("NonPoll_Elec")/P(i))**sigma_I
      nt("NonPoll_Elec") * IntTot("NonPoll_Elec");
 405  * Int_NonPoll_Elec
 406   
 407  Eq19..               Pint("NonPoll_Elec")*IntTot("NonPoll_Elec")     =E= S
      um(i, P(i)*Int_NonPoll_Elec(i));
 408  * Pint("NonPoll_Elec")
 409   
 410   
 411  * Households
 412   
 413   
 414  Eq20(i) $ (ord(i) LE 2)..
 415  Xd(i)                      =E= alpha_C_NonEn(i)**sigma_C * (Pc_NonEn/P(i))
      **sigma_C * C_NonEn;
 416  * Xd(i) $ (ord(i) LE 2)
 417   
 418  Eq21..
 419  Pc_NonEn*C_NonEn           =E= Sum(i $ (ord(i) LE 2), P(i)*Xd(i));
 420  * Pc_nonen
 421   
 422  Eq22(i) $ (ord(i) GE 3)..
 423  Xd(i)                      =E= alpha_C_Energy(i)**sigma_C * (Pc_Energy/(P(
      i)+tax_CO2(i)*CO2_H+Pp(i)*CO2_H))**sigma_C * C_Energy;
 424  * Xd(i) $ (ord(i) GE 3)
 425   
 426  Eq23..
 427  Pc_Energy*C_Energy         =E= Sum(i $ (ord(i) GE 3), (P(i)+tax_CO2(i)*CO2
      _H+Pp(i)*CO2_H)*Xd(i));
 428  * Pc_Energy
 429   
 430   
 431  Eq24(i)..           Y(i)                         =E= Pc_NonEn*C_NonEn + Pc
      _Energy*C_Energy;
 432  * C
 433   
 434  Eq25(i)..           Y(i)                      =E= Sum(f, W(f)*Fs(i,f));
 435  * Y(i)
 436   
 437   
 438  * Investment and Epargne
 439   
 440  Eq26..          INV_Industrie                   =E= Sum(i, S_RDM(i)*Y(i) +
       T_E * Y(i)) ;
 441  * INV_Industrie(i)
 442   
 443  Eq27..             Pinv*INV_Industrie               =E= Sum(i, P(i)*INV_In
      dustrie0(i));
 444  * Pinv
 445  * Equilibrium
 446   
 447  Eq28..             Fd_Industrie("L") + Fd_Services("L") + Fd_Poll_Elec("L"
      ) + Fd_NonPoll_Elec("L")    =E= Sum(i, Fs(i,"L"));
 448  * W("L")
 449   
 450  Eq29..             Fd_Industrie("K") + Fd_Services("K") + Fd_Poll_Elec("K"
      ) + Fd_NonPoll_Elec("K")    =E= Sum(i, Fs(i,"K"));
 451  * W("K")
 452   
 453  Eq30(i)..          Xs(i)             =E= Int_Industrie(i) + Int_Services(i
      ) + Int_NonPoll_Elec(i) + Int_NonPoll_Elec(i) + Xd0(i) + INV_Industrie0(i)
      ;
 454  * P(i)
 455   
EXIT C:\Users\omerk\OneDrive\Documents\gamsdir\projdir\Omer_Kirac_Last.gms
GAMS 41.5.0  2a5a4ddc Jan 3, 2023           WEX-WEI x86 64bit/MS Windows - 04/14/23 17:33:22 Page 2
G e n e r a l   A l g e b r a i c   M o d e l i n g   S y s t e m
Include File Summary


   SEQ   GLOBAL TYPE      PARENT   LOCAL  FILENAME

     1        1 INPUT          0       0  C:\Users\omerk\OneDrive\Documents\gams
                                          dir\projdir\Omer_Kirac_Last.gms
     2       14 LIBINCLUDE     1      14  .C:\GAMS\41\inclib\xlimport.gms
     3       21 IF EXIST       2       7  .C:\Users\omerk\OneDrive\Documents\gam
                                           sdir\projdir\SAM_KIRAC_NORMAND_YILMAZ
                                           .xlsx
     4       39 CALL           2      49  .gdxxrw "SAM_KIRAC_NORMAND_YILMAZ.xlsx
                                           " @xllink.txt log=xllink.log
     5       43 GDXIN          2      53  .C:\Users\omerk\OneDrive\Documents\gam
                                           sdir\projdir\xllink.gdx
     6      456 EXIT           1     425  C:\Users\omerk\OneDrive\Documents\gams
                                          dir\projdir\Omer_Kirac_Last.gms


COMPILATION TIME     =        5.734 SECONDS      3 MB  41.5.0 2a5a4ddc WEX-WEI
GAMS 41.5.0  2a5a4ddc Jan 3, 2023           WEX-WEI x86 64bit/MS Windows - 04/14/23 17:33:22 Page 3
G e n e r a l   A l g e b r a i c   M o d e l i n g   S y s t e m
E x e c u t i o n


----     46 PARAMETER SAM  

               Industrie    Services  Combustil~   Poll_Elec  NonPoll_E~

Industrie                     60.000
Services          10.000
Combustiles       50.000      60.000                  60.000
Poll_Elec         80.000     120.000
NonPoll_Elec      80.000      50.000
L                220.000     600.000                 260.000     190.000
K                200.000     400.000                  90.000      40.000
Total            640.000    1290.000     200.000     410.000     230.000
RDM                                      200.000

           +           L           K           H  Investiss~       Total

Industrie                                380.000     200.000     640.000
Services                                1280.000                1290.000
Combustiles                               30.000                 200.000
Poll_Elec                                210.000                 410.000
NonPoll_Elec                             100.000                 230.000
L                                                               1270.000
K                                                                730.000
H               1270.000     730.000                 300.000    2300.000
Total           1270.000     730.000    2300.000     500.000
RDM                                                              200.000
Epargne                                  300.000                 500.000

           +         RDM

Total            200.000
Epargne          200.000

**** Exec Error at line 170: division by zero (0)

----    199 PARAMETER alpha_Fd_Industrie  Parameter in the second nest of the CE
                                          S production functions

L 0.274,    K 0.227


----    199 PARAMETER alpha_Fd_Services  Parameter in the second nest of the CES
                                         production functions

L 0.360,    K 0.160


----    199 PARAMETER alpha_Fd_Poll_Elec  Parameter in the second nest of the CE
                                          S production functions

L 0.552,    K 0.066


----    199 PARAMETER alpha_Fd_NonPoll_Elec  Parameter in the second nest of the
                                             CES production functions

L 0.682,    K 0.030


----    199 PARAMETER W0  Price of factor f

L 1.000,    K 1.000


----    199 PARAMETER P0  Price of commodity i

Industrie    1.000,    Services     1.000,    Combustiles  1.000
Poll_Elec    1.000,    NonPoll_Elec 1.000


----    199 PARAMETER Y0  Income of households

Industrie    2300.000,    Services     2300.000,    Combustiles  2300.000
Poll_Elec    2300.000,    NonPoll_Elec 2300.000


----    199 PARAMETER Xd0  Demand of commodity i by households

Industrie     380.000,    Services     1280.000,    Combustiles    30.000
Poll_Elec     210.000,    NonPoll_Elec  100.000


----    199 PARAMETER Xs0  Production of sector i

Industrie     640.000,    Services     1290.000,    Combustiles   200.000
Poll_Elec     410.000,    NonPoll_Elec  230.000


----    199 PARAMETER Fd0_Industrie  Demand of factor f by industry

L 220.000,    K 200.000


----    199 PARAMETER Fd0_Services  Demand of factor f by services

L 600.000,    K 400.000


----    199 PARAMETER Fd0_Poll_Elec  Demand of factor f by elec_p

L 260.000,    K  90.000


----    199 PARAMETER Fd0_NonPoll_Elec  Demand of factor f by elec_np

L 190.000,    K  40.000


----    199 PARAMETER Fs0  Supply of factor f by households

                       L           K

Industrie       1270.000     730.000
Services        1270.000     730.000
Combustiles     1270.000     730.000
Poll_Elec       1270.000     730.000
NonPoll_Elec    1270.000     730.000


----    199 PARAMETER CO2  

Services  0.500,    Poll_Elec 1.200,    Industry  1.000


----    199 PARAMETER CO2_H                =        0.800  CO2 emission coeffici
                                                           ents for consumption


EXECUTION TIME       =        0.000 SECONDS      4 MB  41.5.0 2a5a4ddc WEX-WEI```


I am doing modelling work that takes into account the impact on the environment. All parameters are available in the code.
````